# Is there a way to record actions in max to a maxscript array?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

much like the macrorecorder from 3dsmax:

http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-E39D5C20-AF26-49A2-AD21-5D7492B0C0DC.htm,topicNumber=d30e6772

I'd like my commands recorded and saved to a variable (preferably appended to an array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Change Handlers and Callbacks](https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-1BE2E978-72CF-495C-81D6-2B36E2C4FFC7) chapter in 3DS Max reference. Also worth noting that unlike callbacks, what gets output to the macrorecorder stream only depends on a textual output that the plugin developer(s) decide to output and as such it's can be (and often is) wrong and/or incomplete.